# JPA and JSON operator native update query

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, jsonb

I'm trying to make this query work in JPA:

```
UPDATE billing_log_criteria
SET value = jsonb_set(value, '{cubPersonId}', '"12778269"')
where value ->> 'cubPersonId' = '12778268';
```

It works perfectly with postgresql but when I integrate it with JPA, I get the following error:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Following is the query i tried

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=false)
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE billing_log_criteria "
        + "SET value = jsonb_set(value, '{cubPersonId}',  jsonb_set(value, '{cubPersonId}', :newId)) "
        + "where value ->> 'cubPersonId' = :oldId", nativeQuery = true)
void updateCubPersonId(@Param("newId") String newId,@Param("oldId") String oldId);
```

calling like this

```
String oldId = "12778269";
updateCubPersonId( "'\" 12778268l \"'",oldId);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `psql`, the argument `'{cubPersonId}'` is automagically converted to a `text[]`. In JDBC, this is not the case and you need to explicitly, e.g.:

```java
@Query(value = "UPDATE billing_log_criteria "
        + "SET value = jsonb_set(value, '{cubPersonId}'::text[],  jsonb_set(value, '{cubPersonId}'::text[], to_jsonb(:newId::text))) "
        + "where value ->> 'cubPersonId' = :oldId", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: above mentioned code didn't work. :newId and = :oldId is still issue anyways

Comment: Can you add to your question which error you are getting? Just fixed the type conversion for function `jsonb_set`, but parameter `oldId` should already be a `character varying` or `text`, which are comparable.